# Can a Rake task on Heroku time out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, heroku

I'm using Heroku and would like to have a script (on another server) called via cron that periodically requests an action on my Heroku app.  This action will in turn run some processing that may take 1 or 2 minutes to complete.  I believe Heroku has 30 second request limit, I was thinking could call a Rake task from my controller action instead.

Would this work?  I'm curious if anyone has tried this yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a background job on a worker for this.  Your periodic process would then just have to start the worker and it wouldn't matter how long the process took.

Comment: Thanks.  But I should have added that I'd like to avoid a background worker.  I only need to do this periodically and adding a workers would be a bit costly for this.  I was hoping a rake task would do the trick.

Comment: You can dynamically control the number of workers you have, you can fire one up just for the duration required to execute your task.

Comment: Can i execute a worker via an HTTP request that calls a rake task?

Comment: You'd most likely make a web request to a restful service which would register a new delayed_job.  This would get picked up by the worker immediately.

Comment: thanks this is very helpful.  so, i could have a controller action that uses the heroku client lib to create a worker upon request.  but, how could i tear the worker down after the job completed?

Comment: At the end of your task start a new delayed_job task to bring the worker down.  I haven't tried this, so I'm not sure if it'd work, but it'd be worth a try.  Have you also looked at using a cron task?

Answer (score 4):

The rake task would work as long as you don't use a HTTP request as proxy to initiate the task. In fact, if the task is forked from a HTTP Request, the timeout will be the same of the HTTP request.

You should a different method to start the task. Either a crontab (on Heroku side) or a Worker as good solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I've just created a gem to solve exactly this problem. It allows you to queue up any rake task as a delayed_job e.g.

```
rake delay:db:seed
```

which will execute

```
rake db:seed
```

as a delayed_job. You can find it at http://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_task or http://blog.opsb.co.uk/long-running-rake-tasks-on-heroku.